# connect MS SQL database to railo datasources

Tags: sql-server-2005, coldfusion, sql-server-express, railo

I'm having a heck of a time getting a MS SQL datasource connected through my railo installation. I can connect fine through Adobe ColdFusion, but railo keeps throwing an error

In Adobe ColdFusion I have my server set as `mycomputername\sqlexpress` and port 1433. In Railo using the same server, database, username and password. I'm getting the following error

`The TCP/IP connection to the host myservername, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".`.

I've also tried connecting via the IP address listed in SQL Server Configuration Manager IP4 is set to active and enabled with an IP address of 127.0.0.1 but that throws the same error as above

I have IPv6 turned on and that shows up as IP1 in my TCP/IP settings, but I don't know why that would be causing an issue.

Port 1433 is open as I can connect through Adobe ColdFusion. I hope I'm missing something obvious, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Is `sqlexpress` an instance running on `mycomputername`? I have had issues (and [raised a bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3042666)) with Adobe CF version 9 - it cannot connect using the named instance. Anyway, I know you are asking about Railo. I bring this up because the work-around that may work for you is to connect to the server name, `mycomputername` and then specify the port for the instance, instead of the instance name. Of course this all assumes you are attempting to connect to an instance in the first place.

Comment: @Miguel-F It is an instance and I believe I tried that syntax, but I will confirm once I get home tonight.

Comment: Just make sure you specify that instance's port number, not the default of 1433.

Comment: @Miguel-F I was able to get it working with your comment and then this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/07/17/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-listen-on-different-ports-on-different-ip-addresses.aspx Under TCP/IP properties I had `listen all` set to yes which was apparently my issue because it's working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working. Be sure to add it as an answer cause it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working by changing the `Listen All` setting to `no` in SQL Server Configuration Manager > TCP/IP Propertiest

[image: TCP/IP Properties]

and setting the TCP Port to 1433 and enabling the datasource in IP2 below

[image: IP Addresses]